# Access parent lambda parameters when lambda expressions defined individually

Tags: kotlin, jvm, rx-java2

In an RxJava2/RxKotlin application, I am subscribing to an `Observable` inside the `Consumer<T>` passed to the subscribe method of another `Observable`, like so:

```
Observable.defer{ T.toObservable() }
    .delaySubscription(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .subscribeOn(schedulerOne)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .filter { t -> "TestName" == t.name }
    .subscribe {t ->
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Start Consumer 1
        .subscribeOn(schedulerOne)
        .take(6)
        .doOnComplete{ t.action() }
        .subscribe { i: Int ->
            t.anotherAction() // Consumer 2
        }
    }
}
```

However, to cleanup the code, I want to separate Consumer 1 and Consumer 2 into their own `val`s. The problem is that I cannot create a lambda for Consumer 2 as it depends on `t` and there's no way I know of for "informing" a lambda that there will be another variable in scope, which is *not* a parameter. Do you have any architecture advice?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I'm aware I should define the inner `Observable` outside of the `subscribe`, but I'm including it all together to give perspective on what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second consumer doesn't depend on anything, so let's start of by defining that as it's own function:

```
val consumer2 = (T) -> Unit = { it.anotherAction() }
```

Now consumer1 does not need to know explicitly about it's inner consumer's behavior. So for example you could define it like this, but it's defined as a `fun`, not a `val`:

```
fun consumer1(innerConsumer: (T) -> Unit): (T) -> Unit {
  return { t -> Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(schedulerOne)
    .take(6)
    .doOnComplete{ t.action() }
    .subscribe { i: Int ->
        innerConsumer(t)
    }
  }
}
```

And the final code will become like:

```
Observable.defer{ T.toObservable() }
    .delaySubscription(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .subscribeOn(schedulerOne)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .filter { t -> "TestName" == t.name }
    .subscribe { t -> 
      val totalConsumer = consumer1(consumer2)
      totalConsumer(t)
    }
```

If you really want it to be a `val` and you don't care that `consumer1` uses `consumer2` internally, it becomes like this:

```
val consumer1: (T) -> Unit = { t -> 
  Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(schedulerOne)
    .take(6)
    .doOnComplete{ t.action() }
    .subscribe { i: Int ->
        consumer2(t)
    }
}
```

And then your final code will be like this:

```
Observable.defer{ T.toObservable() }
    .delaySubscription(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .subscribeOn(schedulerOne)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .filter { t -> "TestName" == t.name }
    .subscribe { t -> consumer1(t) }
```

On a related note: Instead of starting a new `Observable` within a `subscribe` method, have you considered using `flatMap`?

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me better understand Kotlin and RxJava.